# Inverted Umbrella

Tags: usa

In reference to the patent: [WO2011002413A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2011002413A1)

I found this European patent for an "Improved Umbrella Design." How can I find out if there is a USA patent on this design?

Comment: Hello Amy: Ask Patents is a community-run website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patents or Applications. Unfortunately, questions about the production of products covered by these patents is outside the scope of this site. I edited your question to focus on the portion asking about a US-equivalent patent. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: This is a PCT application number.

Comment: Where is the European Patent you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The application is deemed withdrawn, see here:
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP09846920&tab=main

Since there is no family member mentioned for the US (only TW) it is almost sure that there is no protection for this in the US.

Good luck.

Comment: There might well be other similar patents in the US.